# systemd equivalent of upstart's “respawn limit”

Tags: systemd

I am trying to make a systemd file that will monitor a service and restart it if it crashes. Here's the tricky part: If the service crashes more than 5 times in a minute, I want to mark it as failed and stop trying to automatically restart it. With Upstart, this was easily done with "respawn limit."

Systemd can rate-limit the automatic restarting with StartLimitIntervalSec, but that's not what I want. I don't want to merely rate-limit the restarting, but rather give up entirely if the limit gets hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`systemd.unit(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.unit.5.en.html) manpage, under `StartLimitIntervalSec=, StartLimitBurst=`:

> Note that units which are configured for Restart= and which reach the start limit are not attempted to be restarted anymore; however, they may still be restarted manually at a later point, from which point on, the restart logic is again activated. Note that systemctl reset-failed will cause the restart rate counter for a service to be flushed, which is useful if the administrator wants to manually start a unit and the start limit interferes with that.

… so it'd appear that systemd's start rate limiting does what you want.